# Scroll event won't fire what so ever

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom-events

I have a (fairly simple) issue and I'm breaking my head over it.

The issue is pretty simple - `scroll` event won't fire (ever).

I'm writing this angular project, so I've tried the following:

```
angular.element($window).bind('scroll', ()=> {
    console.log('scroll!');
    if (!scope.scrollPosition) {
      scope.scrollPosition = 0;
    }
    // Alerting for test cause wtf is going on
    scope.boolChangeClass = this.pageYOffset > 600 ? alert(true) : alert(false);
    scope.scrollPosition = this.pageYOffset;
    scope.$apply();
  }
);
```

but nothing happened. (assume `$window` is intact and that i'm using webpack etc.)
This example works great if I change the `scroll` to `click`. weird.

So I've tried vanilla~~!

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
  console.log('test')
})
```

This attempt works on *every* other website *except* mine (gotta admit it's classic).

So - has anyone ever dealt with this and knows what's going on?

I assume that some other element is consuming this event at early stage thus not letting it bubble up. Yet this is just an assumption.'

Would love to understand this :)

=== EDIT ===

I've tried to see all the fired events using `monitorEvents(window)` (using Chrome) and I see *every* event that's being fire **except** the scroll..

Comment: If it doesn't work even with vanilla JS, are you sure the window is actually scrolling? Couldn't it be that it's another element that is scrolling instead? Hard to tell without some working code.

Comment: @JoseFaeti the window is actually scrolling. 100%.

Comment: Following @JoseFaeti's comment - provide a live-working example (jsfiddle/codepen), otherwise it's really hard to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: Please try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fc98zvch/. Does it log the scroll event in the console during scrolling? If yes, and this same code isn't working in your case, then it's not the window that is scrolling in your case.

Comment: @JoseFaeti as I mentioned in my post, this kind of event IS firing on every other site.
I agree with you that it may not be the window that's being scrolled, but how can I catch who's consuming this event?

Comment: @Aviad the fact the same event is firing on other sites doesn't mean that it's the same element that is firing it. To realize who's firing the event you either attach an event listener to every element, or you do an informed guess based on the layout and style of the web page.

Comment: @JoseFaeti I see your guess was pretty quick :)
For general knowledge - is there any way to see what element is firing which event?

Comment: It all comes down to experience really :) The scroll event doesn't bubble, so to see which element is scrolling, you have to attach a scroll event handler to every element possibly, which is impractical of course.

Comment: For events that bubbles, you can just attach an event handler to the body element and that's it. Providing no other element is consuming the event, that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's the body element that is scrolling. Try adding the following code in the console.

```
document.body.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  console.log('test');
});
```